# Itunes connect metadata rejected

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I submitted my app to app store one week ago. Now I got a message from apple:

> We began the review of your app but aren't able to continue because we
>   need additional information about your app.
>
> At your earliest opportunity, please review the following question(s)
>   and provide as much detailed information as you can. The more
>   information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your
>   review.
>
> - How does the user chat anonymously? Please provides all the steps for the review?
>
> Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested
>   information, we can proceed with your review

I provided the information in resolution center. But my app status is "Metadata rejected" and "Submit for review" button is active.

Do I need submit the app again? Or I have to wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resubmit with the updated information.